# Data is not binding in Xamarin android app

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin.forms, data-binding

I have created a reusable component foor Patient card with icon and text:

```cs
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class PatientInfoCard : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty TitleProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        nameof(Title),
        typeof(string),
        typeof(PatientInfoCard),
        default(string)
    );
    
    public string Title
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(TitleProperty);
        set => SetValue(TitleProperty, value);
    }
    
    public PatientInfoCard()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Its xaml:

```xml
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MobileApp.Control.PatientInfoCard">
  <ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout Background="green" Padding="10" >
            <StackLayout Margin="10,10,10,0" BackgroundColor="gray">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Title}" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                    <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Title}" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                </Grid>
                <Label Text="{Binding Description}" Margin="10,5,10,10" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
  </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

Then I try to use it in a grid:

```xml
<Grid Margin="10" Grid.Row="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" RowSpacing="10" ColumnSpacing="10"
      x:DataType="Control:PatientInfoCard">
    <Control:PatientInfoCard Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Title="Vaistai"/>
    <Control:PatientInfoCard Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Title="Tyrimai" />
    <Control:PatientInfoCard Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  Title="Ligos"/>
    <Control:PatientInfoCard Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Title="Alergijos"/>
    <Control:PatientInfoCard Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  Title="Skiepai"/>
</Grid>
```

It gives me only 5 blocks template (no Title and Icon):

[image: 5 block template without values]

So I guess that binding values are not working properly? What do my code lack of?

Comment: Have you tried setting the BindingContext on the PatientInfoCard to itself?

Comment: Now I tried to add it to Grid: <Grid BindingContext="Control:PatientInfoCard"  ......
And it helped a little because a breakpoint on InitializeComponent() in PatientInfoCard is being hit. But binded values are still not shown...

Comment: Where is the `Description` property that you're trying to bind to coming from? The `BindingContext` on the Grid isn't necessary. Also, where's the model class? Do you have a model class?

Comment: Isnt PatientInfoCard a model class? Also, thank, I accepted your answer. Adding BindingContext = this; in constructor after InitializeComponent() worked well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to bind from a View's XAML to its own code-behind is to define an `x:Name` for the XAML-part, e.g. `PatientCard` and then use `x:Reference PatientCard` as a `Source` in the Binding:

```xml
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MobileApp.Control.PatientInfoCard"
             x:Name="PatientCard">
  <ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout Background="green" Padding="10" >
            <StackLayout Margin="10,10,10,0" BackgroundColor="gray">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Label Grid.Column="0"
                           Text="{Binding Title, Source={x:Reference PatientCard}}"
                           FontAttributes="Bold"
                           VerticalOptions="Center" />

                    <!-- ... -->

                </Grid>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
  </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

*Alternatively*, you can also set the `BindingContext = this;` or to a ViewModel or Model class in the code-behind:

```cs
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class PatientInfoCard : ContentView
{
    //...

    public PatientInfoCard()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked! THe second option. Altough, I think first one would work too. Interesting why there wasnt clear instructions about the need of  BindingContext = this;. i wasted so much time on that.... Thank you @ewerspej